# Vim - opening man pages

Tags: vim, keyboard-shortcuts

I'm aware that exists a shortcut to open manpage of current function (the function cursor is on), but I can't recall how to do that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're looking for <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd> - [`:help K`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/various.txt.html#K):

> Run a program to lookup the keyword under the cursor.  The name of the program is given with the 'keywordprg' option (default is "man").